# Grails how to show HQL JOIN value in g:each

Tags: hibernate, join, grails, groovy, hql

i want to ask how can i show this code result on view page

**Controller**

```
query =" select subs.firstName, trx.currentBalance from Transaction trx, Subscriber subs where 
trx.subscriberID = subs.msisdn and trx.subscriberID = '0' and trx.date ='2020-09-04'"
query= Transaction.executeQuery(query);
```

---

with this code :

**View Page**

```
<g:each in="${listQueryTable}" status="i" var="userInstance">
<tr>
<td>${userInstance.firstName}</td>      <-- this code does not work for me
<td>${userInstance.currentBalance}</td> <-- this code does not work for me
</tr>
</g:each>
```

Comment: `this code does not work for me` what do you mean?

Comment: @injecteer i want to call firstName , but it show me an error like this :  No such property: firstName for class: java.lang.String.

if i use ${userInstance.subs.firstName}, the error like this : subs for class: TransactionController

Comment: what if you print `${userInstance}`

Comment: @injecteer
if i use ${userInstance}, the result is :
[Ljava.lang.Object;@bf8538
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1c35334

Comment: print `${userInstance.getClass()}` also

Comment: in controller, if i print query i got result like this : INI : [[0, System]]

Comment: so, you should be using indices to print out values in GSP: `${userInstance[ 0 ]}` which correspond to field positions in select clause

Comment: @injecteer thank you very much.. i got the values. you are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HQL query like yours in the controller you can display the values of it in the GSP using indicies like so:

```
<g:each in="${listQueryTable}" status="i" var="userInstance">
<tr>
<td>${userInstance[0]}</td> 
<td>${userInstance[1]}</td>
</tr>
</g:each>
```

because each element of `listQueryTable` is an `Object[]`.

As a variation, you can turn each list's element into a map like so:

```
query =" select subs.firstName, trx.currentBalance, ..."
listQueryTable = Transaction.executeQuery(query).collect{ [ firstName:it[0], currentBalance:it[1], ... ] }
```

then you can use your original GSP for display.

The proper solution would be to get rid of raw HQL query and use Hibernate/GORM means to build the model for View. You have to add a reference between you domain classes and use dynamic finders or criteria query.